# Scientific visualization in Android

Tags: android, visualization

I would like to visualize mesh-based scientific data on Android device as can typically done with VTK/Paraview on PC. My preference is ease of use and robustness. I research on the web and see that VTK has quite a poor support for mobile application. Do you have suggestion for an alternative?